# save the username of the one who played an audio, but not saving a list

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

theres the issue: i want to register the LAST USER who played an audio that is on my bot, for example:

if some called B calls and AUDIO, after that if i type "ultimarata" my bot should say: the last one was B

and repeat this everytime someone calls an audio, i just want the bot show THE LAST ONE, not a list of the ones who have done it..

here is my code:

```
const discord = require ("discord.js")
const config = require('../config.json')

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    message.delete({ timeout: 200 })
    let rata = message.member.username;
    const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
    if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send("No estas en el canal de voz.");

    voiceChannel.join()
   .then(connection => {
      connection.play('C:/Users/juanchy/Desktop/DiscordBot/musica/audio.mp3', { volume: 1.99 });

      bot.on("message", async message => {
        if (message.author.bot) return;
        if (message.channel.type === "dm") return;
            
        let prefix = config.prefix;
        let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
        let command = messageArray[0].toLowerCase();
        let args = messageArray.slice(1);
        const ratis = 'ultimarata'
        
        if(command ===`${ratis}`) {
            message.channel.send(`The last one was ${rata}`)
        }
    
        if(!command.startsWith(prefix)) return;
        
    
    
    
        let cmd = bot.commands.get(command.slice(prefix.length));
        if (cmd) cmd.run(bot, message, args);
    });
   });       
};


  
     
module.exports.help = {
    name: 'audio'
}
```

the problem with my code is that, this is happening:

same example as before:

if some called B calls an AUDIO, after that if anyone type "ultimarata" my bot will say: the last one was B

but this time after 15 mins, someone called C calls an AUDIO, so if anyone type "ultimarata" my bot will say:  the last one was B, The last one was C

and what i dont want, i just want to save the last one who plays the audio, not a recount, i hope i was  clear as possible, thank you!

Comment: Are you using multiple `message` events?

Comment: i do, is that not correcT?

Comment: That's not correct. you should never have multiple `message` events. Remove the `message` events that are inside the modules. I think removing them should work. You should only have one message event, that should be in the main file.